# How to combine these two sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not very experienced in sql but can generally get by in structuring basic queries, but this is too complex for me to work out.

I have two queries which each give the results I need individually, however I need to combine them to get the final result I need.

In one query it grabs all "scores" for a particular student and returns an average. In the other query I strip the highest and lowest records from the table.

I want to combine these queries to first strip the highest and lowest scores, then to return the average score from ONLY the remaining records. Please help guide me to the correct syntax to use.

my queries:

---

This returns ALL the highest and lowest scores:

```
SELECT *
FROM `scores`
WHERE `tot_score` = (
SELECT MAX( `tot_score` )
FROM `scores` )
OR `tot_score` = (
SELECT MIN( `tot_score` )
FROM `scores` )
```

---

This returns the average scores:

```
SELECT `pres_id`, COUNT( `pres_id` ) , ROUND( AVG( `tot_score` ) , 2 ) , `username`, `name`, `pres_day`
FROM `scores`, `users`
WHERE `users.id_user` = `scores.pres_id`
GROUP BY `pres_id`
```

How can I combine these to get the result I need?

Comment: what do u mean by combined show some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you do the calculation of the min and max values in a single subquery.  Then you can simply take the rows that you want using a `where` clause to filter:

```
SELECT s.`pres_id`, COUNT( `pres_id` ), ROUND( AVG( `tot_score` ) , 2 ) ,
       `username`, `name`, `pres_day`
FROM `scores` s join
     `users` u
     on u.id_user = s.pres_id join
     (select s.pres_id, max(tot_score) as maxts, min(tot_score) as mints
      from scores s
      group by s.pres_id
     ) ssum
     on u.id_user = ssum.pres_id
where s.tot_score > ssum.mints and s.tot_score < ssum.maxts
GROUP BY s.`pres_id`;
```

I am guessing that you want to strip the highest and lowest scores for each student.  If you just want to omit the highest and lowest for *all* students, then use the following:

```
SELECT s.`pres_id`, COUNT( `pres_id` ), ROUND( AVG( `tot_score` ) , 2 ) ,
       `username`, `name`, `pres_day`
FROM `scores` s join
     `users` u
     on u.id_user = s.pres_id cross join
     (select max(tot_score) as maxts, min(tot_score) as mints
      from scores s
     ) ssum
where s.tot_score > ssum.mints and s.tot_score < ssum.maxts
GROUP BY s.`pres_id`;
```

EDIT:

Modification to keep score when there is only one score for a student:

```
SELECT s.`pres_id`, COUNT( `pres_id` ), ROUND( AVG( `tot_score` ) , 2 ) ,
       `username`, `name`, `pres_day`
FROM `scores` s join
     `users` u
     on u.id_user = s.pres_id join
     (select s.pres_id, max(tot_score) as maxts, min(tot_score) as mints,
             count(*) as cnt
      from scores s
      group by s.pres_id
     ) ssum
     on u.id_user = ssum.pres_id
where (s.tot_score > ssum.mints and s.tot_score < ssum.maxts) or (cnt = 1)
GROUP BY s.`pres_id`;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your response. I noticed an error in your syntax (backticks on cross join). The query ran without error and initially appears to return the result I need, though I will need to check a few records to see if it gives me the desired result...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to strip the max and min score (each instance of) from each student score and return the average of the remaining results for each student.  When I try to run your first query it returns a "#1052 - Column 'pres_id' in field list is ambiguous error"

Comment: @user1734104 . . . It needed the alias to specify which table it came from.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your first query returned the correct results, though I have since thought, "what if all the scores were the same value for one student record", I guess this would return an average score value of zero, is that correct? If so, how easy would it be adapt the query to leave one record as the result?  If it is not such a simple edit to do, I might post as another question.

Comment: @user1734104 . . . You need to decide what to do when all the values for a student are either the maximum or minimum value.  You can ask another question, refer to this one, and clarify what the rules are for this situation.  But, I'm going to make a small change that will keep the values when there is only one score for a student.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to *invert* the high/low scores query and then use it as a result set in the existing average query:

```
SELECT `pres_id`, COUNT( `pres_id` ) , ROUND( AVG( `tot_score` ) , 2 ) , `username`, `name`, `pres_day`
FROM (
    SELECT `tot_score`
    FROM `scores`
    WHERE `tot_score` <> (
    SELECT MAX( `tot_score` )
    FROM `scores` )
    OR `tot_score` <> (
    SELECT MIN( `tot_score` )
    FROM `scores` ) 
) AS `scores`, `users`
WHERE `users.id_user` = `scores.pres_id`
GROUP BY `pres_id`
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ran the query but it returns a #1054 - Unknown column 'pres_id' in 'field list'. I also tried changing the SELECT to 'scores.pres_id' but still returns the same error "Unknown column". Any ideas?

Comment: @user1734104, then just change the inner query to select those additional fields.